# Не отображаюся привязанные данные в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть страница `AddGoodPage`, в атрибутах задано свойство

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Также есть `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock     Grid.Column="1"
               Width="147"
               Height="35"
               Margin="70,10,0,0"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Text="{Binding Path=PurTitle}" />
```

В котором задана привязка. В code-behind следующее

```
        public string PurTitle
        { get; set; }

        public AddGoodPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PurTitle = "SOMETEXT";
        }
```

Но ничего не отображается. Причем остальные поля для ввода привязываю также (еще там `Mode=TwoWay` есть) и они работают, правда только в одну сторону - данные я получаю, а вот когда я присваиваю пустые строки соответствующим свойствам ничего не происходит). В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, что происходит.

Как правильно замечает в своём ответе @ixSci, вы должны были реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, или сделать `PurTitle` `DependencyProperty` (в Visual Studio для этого есть сниппет `propdp`: попробуйте набрать внутри класса `propdp` и два раза нажать на <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

Без этого привязка не может узнать об изменении значения вашего свойства.

Сама привязка устанавливается как часть вызова `InitializeComponent();`, и поскольку вы устанавливаете значение `PurTitle` после этого, новое, правильное значение не подхватывается `Binding`'ом.

---

Если бы вы переставили местами эти две строки:

```
public AddGoodPage()
{
    PurTitle = "SOMETEXT";
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

— то первоначальное значение было бы отображено правильно. Но последующие изменения `PurTitle` всё равно не подхватывались бы `Binding`'ом без INPC или `DependencyProperty`.

Answer (score 3):

У Вас простое свойство, когда Вы его изменяете, WPF не может узнать об этом. Для того, чтобы WPF могло узнать, свойство должно быть типа [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). Либо же, класс содержащий свойство, должен реализовывать интерфейс [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) и явно вызывать нужный метод в `set`(пример есть по ссылке).